# how to send parameter to job class for scheduling with QUARTZ.NET

Tags: asp.net, quartz.net, job-scheduling

i want to use quartz scheduling method to evaluate a value and save that on changing
i create a schedule class like this :

```
public static void Start()
    {   
        IScheduler Scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        Scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<UpdateDailyFee>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
              (s =>
                 //s.WithIntervalInHours(24)
                     s.WithIntervalInSeconds(3)
                .OnEveryDay()

              )
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        Scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

and class that i want to pass parameter (a numeric value) to Job Class
the job class is like this and i dont know how to pass value from program code to this job class:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        //int xxx = value that should retrieve here 
        throw new NotImplementedException();

    }
```

how pass parameter (for example int value) from a page to Execute(Parameter)?

Comment: Where does this value come from? And why is it not also available in your job? You can use the [JobDataMap](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/more-about-jobs.html) to pass values to your jobs but this is not the best way to achieve that.

Comment: how to pass input parameter to job class? in scheduler class how do i declare a variable and assign value to that ? if i declare variable and value with UsingJobData() in JobBuilder , this will be static value! i can not got it!

Comment: _Where does this value come from? And why is it not also available in your job?_